# SQL lag window and custom logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

I am working on this dataset
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=447a5d2c33b04346e70dab0a8d098655

Custom logic:
Grouped by name, testcentre, coursename, testtype.
If a retest is taken, then scores are compared - if higher the highest one precedes or original score.

Lag:
Based on above selected row, if a lag window exists between the remaining set of records example within 4 days , then the higest score record shall be picked up.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Sample data

```
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| recordid | Name  | testcentre | coursename | testtype | testscore |  testdate  | retestflag | Preferred_Output |                 RejectReason                  |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|        1 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 01/02/2019 |          0 |                0 |                                               |
|        3 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 02/02/2019 |          1 |                1 | Better score in retest                        |
|        4 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | TOEFL    |        80 | 04/02/2019 |          0 |                0 | Within 4 days of previous test                |
|       21 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 02/02/2018 |          1 |                1 | marked as retest without base.needs inclusion |
|        5 | Jack  | London     | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 01/02/2019 |          0 |                1 | Same or bad score in retest                   |
|        8 | Jack  | London     | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 02/02/2019 |          1 |                0 | Same or bad score in retest                   |
|        7 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | IELTS    |        70 | 01/02/2019 |          0 |                1 | Same score in retest                          |
|       11 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | IELTS    |        70 | 02/02/2019 |          1 |                0 | Same score in retest                          |
|       13 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | TOEFL    |       100 | 04/02/2019 |          0 |                0 | Within 4 days of previous test                |
|       55 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 01/02/2016 |          0 |                1 | Older test, no follow on                      |
|       60 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 01/08/2019 |          0 |                1 | same score in retest                          |
|       61 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 02/08/2019 |          1 |                0 |                                               |
|       62 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | TOEFL    |        80 | 04/01/2020 |          0 |                1 | More than 4 days, included                    |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Desired Output

```
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
| recordid | Name  | testcentre | coursename | testtype | testscore |  testdate  | retestflag | Preferred_Output |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
|        3 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 02/02/2019 |          1 |                1 |
|       21 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 02/02/2018 |          1 |                1 |
|        5 | Jack  | London     | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 01/02/2019 |          0 |                1 |
|        7 | Louis | Brazil     | English    | IELTS    |        70 | 01/02/2019 |          0 |                1 |
|       55 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        90 | 01/02/2016 |          0 |                1 |
|       60 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | IELTS    |        95 | 01/08/2019 |          0 |                1 |
|       62 | Sam   | Paris      | English    | TOEFL    |        80 | 04/01/2020 |          0 |                1 |
+----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* are much appreciated.

Comment: Have included the sample data and desired outputs, sorry for missing it  earlier.

Comment: Why the rows with testtype = 'TOEFL' don't appear in the results?

Comment: @Sethu . . . Your data has no examples of retests that are more than four days later, making it unclear what to do in that situation.

Comment: @Gordon have included the additional data set for edge cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data and description, this seems to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, testcentre, coursename, testtype order by testscore desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by name, testcentre, coursename, testtype) as cnt
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and cnt >= 2;
```

This does *not* include the condition on "within 4 days", because that condition is not clearly explained.  What happens if there are a series of 5 tests, each 3 days apart, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by testscore desc) rn
  from test
) t
where rn = 1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=2210726c2ee29aa8d69f7059a1dd953a)